# How to enable an endpoint in Spring Actuator 1.4.5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

We run Spring boot 1.4.5 and Spring Cloud Config 1.1.0

I want to enable to endpoint /actuator/refresh in application.properties

In Spring's tutorial the say I should use this property:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

but this property is not supported on my spring boot version (tutorial spring boot version is 2.0.5).

What is the property I should use?

Comment: that is for Spring Boot 2.x+, Make sure you reference the correct documentation for you version 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get auto-completion for the properties, if you press ctrl + space, within either the properties or the yaml file? (Then you should see it, or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Apparently the property I needed was:

```
endpoints.refresh.enabled=true
```

worked like a charm.